# Android Paging 3 with LoadStateAdapter - Issue of Screen flickering and jumping when new pages are loaded on scrolling

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I have implemented Paging 3 with RemoteMediator.
And also have a LoadStateAdapter.

Initially, I was experiencing flickers, glitches and jumps when scrolling pages.
This answer worked to resolve the issue -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713643/15392387

I can see 3 items in my RecyclerView in one screen, so setting the PageSize = 8, as suggested, resolved all flickering issues.

But since I also use PagingDataAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter, the initial load when the app is installed, automatically scrolls down to the 8th ListItem.

**It does not start from the top of the page.**

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

I found an answer that might be talking about the same issue, but solution is still unclear -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66763460/15392387

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.bind(view) //View Binding

        val parentAdapter = PlaylistParentPagingAdapter(this, this)

        binding.apply {
            playlistParentRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            playlistParentRecyclerView.adapter = parentAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
             header = PlaylistLoadStateAdapter { parentAdapter.retry() },
             footer = PlaylistLoadStateAdapter { parentAdapter.retry() },
           )

        }

        viewModel.playlists.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            parentAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it)
        }
    }
```

**PlaylistLoadStateAdapter.kt**

```
class PlaylistLoadStateAdapter(private val retry: () -> Unit) :
    LoadStateAdapter<PlaylistLoadStateAdapter.LoadStateViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG = "PlaylistLoadStateAdapte"

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, loadState: LoadState): LoadStateViewHolder {
        val binding = PlaylistLoadStateFooterBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return LoadStateViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LoadStateViewHolder, loadState: LoadState) {
        holder.bind(loadState)
    }

    inner class LoadStateViewHolder(private val binding: PlaylistLoadStateFooterBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.retryButtonFooter.setOnClickListener {
                retry.invoke()
            }
        }

        fun bind(loadState: LoadState) {
            binding.apply {
                Log.d(TAG, "bind: loadstate = $loadState")
                progressBarFooter.isVisible = loadState is LoadState.Loading
                retryButtonFooter.isVisible = loadState !is LoadState.Loading
                errorTextViewFooter.isVisible = loadState !is LoadState.Loading
            }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open feature request for RecyclerView where we need a way to ignore the header / footers when considering restoring scroll position. Essentially you have a list which only contains the footer, then a list which contains some items + the footer, and RV is trying to restore the scroll position to the footer since that is the only overlap.

You can follow the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184874613

One workaround is to use placeholders, but if that's unsuitable you could also try a custom `LoadStateAdapter` that is only visible after `PagingSource` is done loading locally. This will cause your footer to get remove and re-added during local refresh, but it most likely will not be visible to the user.